# the 53 th imo inequality

Tags: inequality

$a_2,a_3,...,a_n$ are all positive reals satisfying $a_2a_3\dots a_n=1$. Prove that

$\prod_2^n(1+a_i)^i>n^n$

Please give a hint on how to approach this.

Comment: At least state the question correctly. $a_1$ is irrelevant, and $a_2,\dots,a_n$ satisfy $a_2a_3\dots a_n=1$.

Comment: sorry i forgot to type that

Comment: Also you only need the \$ signs around the math parts. Type the rest normally outside the \$ signs.

Comment: We also need the condition $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: substitute $a_2=\frac{x_2}{x_1},a_3=\frac{x_3}{x_2},\dots,a_n=\frac{x_1}{x_{n-1}}$ to get $(x_1+x_2)^2(x_2+x_3)^3\dots(x_{n-1}+x_1)^n>n^nx_1^2x_2^3\dots x_{n-1}^n$.

Now use AM/GM for each factor on lhs (after adjusting $(x_2+x_3)$ slightly so that it has three terms not two and similarly for the others).

Comment: how Am /Gm is applied to lhs...

Comment: $(x_2+x_3)^3=(\frac{x_2}{2}+\frac{x_2}{2}+x_3)^3\ge 3^3(\frac{x_2}{2})^2x_3$ etc

Comment: There we get 2^[{(n(n+1))/2}-1]

Comment: No, you have to adjust each factor as indicated above, before using AM/GM. This is an IMO question, you cannot expect it to be trivial! :)

Comment: Also remember to show that the inequality is strict.

Comment: I am a new user.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  You already have a good solution, here is another way:

Use AM-GM after "splitting" the $1$ in the general term to get
$$1+a_i \ge i\sqrt[i]{\frac{a_i}{(i-1)^{i-1}}} \implies (1+a_i)^i \ge \frac{i^i}{(i-1)^{i-1}}a_i$$
Now the product telescopes nicely, and show why equality is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, we also need $n\geq 3$.

By @almagest's hint, we use the AM-GM inequality to get
\begin{align*}
\left(x_1+x_2\right)^2&\geq 2^2x_1x_2,\\
\left(x_2+x_3\right)^3&=\left(2\cdot\frac{x_2}{2}+x_3\right)^3\geq
3^3\cdot\frac{x_2^2}{2^2}\cdot x_3,\\
\left(x_3+x_4\right)^4&=\left(3\cdot\frac{x_3}{3}+x_4\right)^4\geq
4^4\cdot\frac{x_3^3}{3^3}\cdot x_4,\\
&\,\,\,\vdots\\
\left(x_{n-1}+x_1\right)^n&=\left[(n-1)\cdot\frac{x_{n-1}}{n-1}+x_1\right]^n\geq
n^n\cdot\frac{x_{n-1}^{n-1}}{(n-1)^{n-1}}\cdot x_1.
\end{align*}
So we obtain $\left(x_1+x_2\right)^2\left(x_2+x_3\right)^3\cdots\left(x_{n-1}+x_1\right)^{n}\geq n^nx_1^2x_2^3\cdots x_{n-1}^n$. 
However, if the equality holds, then the above $n-1$ equalities must hold simultaneously, which imply 
$$x_1=x_2=2x_3=2\cdot 3 x_4=\cdots=(n-2)!x_{n-1}=(n-1)!x_1.$$
This is a contradiction because $n\geq 3$. So we conclude that
$$\left(x_1+x_2\right)^2\left(x_2+x_3\right)^3\cdots\left(x_{n-1}+x_1\right)^{n}> n^nx_1^2x_2^3\cdots x_{n-1}^n$$
and the result follows immediately.